# Which plugin allows to add the link with button appearance in CKEditor 5?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

Unfortunately, no actual results for search requests like "CKEditor link button" or "ckeditor button appearance link". But I don't believe that it's impossible to add the link as below orange button by CKEditor because it's a basic demand of customers.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use a [decorator](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_link_link-LinkConfig.html#member-decorators). this would part of the config object you pass to `ClassicEditor.create`

```
link: {
    decorators: {
        buttonLink: {
            mode: 'manual',
            label: 'Style as button',
            defaultValue: false,
            attributes: {
                class: 'link-button'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the interface would look like

[image]

then you'd just need to make a css style for `a.link-button` to style as you'd like.

Comment: I've been looking all over for something like this. I knew a custom plugin just for this would be overkill. Thanks!